# Why does Ajax refresh page on mobile devices after submitting form via POST method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am trying form submission on my Django website.
Ajax works fine for form submissions on Desktop and doesn't refresh page on submission, whereas when using on mobile devices the POST data is submitted successfully but the page refreshes after the request.
How can I prevent refresh after submission?

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#email_button_secondary_submit').on('click', function(e){
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right');
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
                $emailaddress = $('#email').val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : '',
                cached: false,
                data: {
                    email: $emailaddress,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('.Subscribe').hide();
                    $('.Thanks').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
                    $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('.Subscribe').hide();
                    $('.Error').show();
                    $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
                    $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
                },
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Edit 1:
I detected that the on click block fails to execute on mobile devices.(I noticed that by adding an alert() after

`$('#email_button_secondary_submit').on('click', function(e){`

Comment: is it o ios or android or both?

Comment: Both on android and ios.
The data is submitted successfully but the page refreshes at the same time.
No issues on desktop

Comment: I'm more surprised that it does work on desktop given that you call e.preventDefault(); after the AJAX statement.

Comment: i think its your jquery version issue, which version are you using?

Comment: jQuery version 3.2.0           
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: try  `return false;` at the end of submit function before  e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2):

Notice the "e" in the 'function(e)'. You should add that. Also make your "e.preventDefault();" just as I have it below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#email_button_secondary_submit').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right');
            $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
            $emailaddress = $('#email').val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : '',
            cached: false,
            data: {
                email: $emailaddress,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function () {
                $('.Subscribe').hide();
                $('.Thanks').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin');
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.Subscribe').hide();
                $('.Error').show();
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
                $('#email_button_secondary_submit > span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
            },
          });
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Made a mistake, change  "e.preventDefault();" to be under the on click function.
    $('#email_button_secondary_submit').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();